# Can I have an ido list displayed when switching buffer in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Initially I used <kbd>C-x b</kbd> (`ido-switch-buffer`) a lot when I want to jump between buffers of recent use.

Nowadays I bind <kbd>command+,</kbd> to `previous-buffer` and <kbd>command+.</kbd> to `next-buffer`, and found it easier and quicker to switch between two or three recent used buffers, but the downside is there's no `ido`-like **list prompt** (so I know where I am in the history list of buffer use).

So the question is how to get an `ido`-like list showing when I call `previous-buffer` or `next-buffer` to do the switching.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea for `previous-buffer` and `next-buffer` to additionally emit a message indicating the buffers that would follow.  You might like to `M-x report-emacs-bug` and request this new feature.

Answer (score 2):

The [iflipb](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/iflipb) package does what you want.